# VB.Net convert formatted string to double

Tags: vb.net, converters

I got a string by formatting a double value, like

```
Dim strFormat = "#,##0.00 weeks"
Dim strDisplayText As String = dblIn.ToString(strFormat) ' dblIn is type Double
```

Then the strDisplayText is displayed in a textbox (of a wpf.datagrid), and the user may edit it. Afterwards, the text should be converted back to an double.

```
Dim dblOut = ???(strDisplayText, strFormat)
 ' dblOut should be the same as dblIn, if strDisplayText wasnt changed.
if dblOut.ToString(strFormat) <> strDisplayText Then
    print("failed conversion.")
end if
```

Double.Parse (and TryParse) fail because of the " weeks" at the end and Val cant process the "," as group seperator.

strFormat is read from a file, so it might be any valid custom or standart numeric format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Split your input string at the space (`string.Split`), verify that the second part is still "weeks" and parse only the first part. However, I'd argue that removing " weeks" from the editable text and showing that information either as a label to the right of your text box or in a header would make for a better user experience.

Comment: "strFormat is read from a file, so it might be any valid custom or standart numeric format" you cannot revert a text that was formatted with an arbitrary format string to the double value. There is no `Double.TryParseExact`(like for `Date`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string methods to remove the `" weeks"` at the end:

```
Dim dblValue = strDisplayText.Remove(strDisplayText.Length - " weeks".Length)
Dim dbl As Double = double.Parse(dblValue)
```

> strFormat is read from a file, so it might be any valid custom or
> standart numeric format

You cannot revert a text that was formatted with an arbitrary format string to the double value. There is no `Double.TryParseExact`(like for `Date`). Especially if you even have different decimal or group separators.

I'd let the user edit the double value, not the formatted text.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I just assumed that a function like this must exist somewhere and that I just failed searching